# "pair" class made from "std::tuple"

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I know that "std::pair" struct does not inherit from "std::tuple" class.
However, I wanted to make "pair" class which inherited from "std::tuple" class.

Is this correct? Are there any other ways?

```cpp
#include <tuple>

template <typename First, typename Second>
class pair : public std::tuple<First, Second> {
public:
  First &first = std::get<0>(*this);
  Second &second = std::get<1>(*this);

  using std::tuple<First, Second>::tuple;
};
```

Comment: Did you test it? Does it work as expected?

Comment: Reference member is often problematic, as default assignation is not the one we might expect.

Comment: You class is bigger than one you might expect from a `pair`.

Comment: imho using inheritance is "wrong". For most aspects a `std::pair` *is* a tuple, there is no need to add polymorphism via inheritance.

Comment: Inheritance isn't the only way C++ does polymorphism. `std::pair` *does* have specialisations for `std::get`, `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element`, so in many ways it *is* a tuple of 2 elements

Comment: What does "is this correct" mean? Did you try to use this object as if it were `std::pair`? Did you get the expected results? Did you not get the expected results, and what happened when you tried to figure out why, with your debugger? How did you try to use your class, as a substitute for `std::pair`? Did you try to use it for everything you use `std::pair` for? What happened?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this correct?

Depends on what you intend to do with the class. If the intention is for it to work like `std::pair`, then it's not correct. Consider following example:

```
std::pair<int, int> std_p1{}, std_p2{};
std_p1 = std_p2; // works

pair<int, int> rin_p1{}, rin_p2{};
rin_p1 = rin_p2; // doesn't work
```

> Are there any other ways?

Certainly. A good way is to not define a custom class inheriting from tuple, but to use `std::pair` instead. That said, I find it difficult to find any use cases for pair types in the first place as in most cases named classes tend to be superior.